# Special type of combination of arbitrary number of lists

Tags: python, function, for-loop, recursion

I encountered this problem while working on an optimization problem. I need a code that takes a list whose elements are zipped lists just like as `A=[zip(a,b) , zip(c,d) , zip(e,f)]` where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are lists and pairwise reverse of each other. I need a code like the following but for A of arbitrary length:

```
a=[0,1]
b=[1,0]
c=[0,1,2]
d=[2,1,0]
e=[0,1,2,3]
f=[3,2,1,0]
result=[]
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    q=['p1']*i
    p=['p2']*j
    for l,k in zip(c,d):
        y=['p1']*l
        x=['p2']*k
        for r,s in zip(e,f):
            m=['p1']*r
            n=['p2']*s
            result.append(q+p+y+x+m+n)
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: If you don't see the resemblance, lmk and I'll write you an answer.

Comment: @wjandrea   Unfortunately I can not get an answer from the link that you sent. I appreciate if you write an answer.